# Use jQuery Autocomplete to search key terms, not strings

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete to search through an array, but need to alter the functionality somehow (or if there is a different method, use that).

I would essentially like autocomplete to search keywords, not strings. What I mean is this:

Perhaps a search is placed for `search term`

And the array contains the following:

```
search one term
search term two
search one two
```

The autocomplete currently returns just 2 (search term two). However, I would like it to return both 1 and 2 (search one term, search term two), as these both contain the words search and term.

Perhaps there is a more efficient way to do this, possibly without jQuery Autocomplete?